# Stuck trying to dual boot ubuntu with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 following this guide https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/ but am facing some problems.

I have created an empty partition. I created a bootable USB stick using Rufus. Then I tried to reboot the machine while pressing F12, F10, or F2 to boot from USB but it only boots into some settings.

[image]

EDIT: The boot option priorities show the following. Do I change Boot Option 1 to UEFI: SanDisk ?

[image]

I cant change the option for Secure Boot but it looks like its already been disabled.

[image]

Comment: Maybe changing the boot order helps.

Comment: @FirstLast Hi, I have added pictures of the boot option priorities. Is that the same as boot order ? If so, then based on the pictures do I just change option #1 to UEFI: SanDisk ?

Comment: Did you try F11 to launch Boot Menu? I've got several machines with this key at home. Don't to forget to disable Secure Boot. Look this: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/509117/booting-from-usb-on-aptio-bios/

Comment: I cant change the option for secure boot but it looks like its already disabled. I tried spamming the F11 key when restarting but it doesn't take me anywhere.

Comment: hello help please

Comment: YES, obviously change the boot option #1 to "UEFI: SanDisk"... Optionally read your manual or other online resources to check whether it has a "one time boot" menu (and the respective key) the other mentioned alluded to with F11 (it varies a lot). This feature is only useful for occasionally booting external media without always going to UEFI settings to do that.